# numpy ravel on inconsistent dimensional object

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have below code that allows me to iterate over a flattened list and maps the updates back to the structured array -

```
a = np.asarray([1,2,3])
b = np.asarray([4,5,6])
c = np.asarray([a, b])
print c
r = c.ravel()
print r
r[1] = 10
print c
```

setting r[1] = 10 modifies c[0][1] to 10. I want to do something similar with the lower snippet but this fails and I am assuming it's because the dimensions are inconsistent. Is there some way to get similar behavior so I can modify a flattened version without having to reshape it back to c?

```
a = np.asarray([1,2,3])
b = np.asarray([4,5,6,7,8])
c = np.asarray([a, b])

r = c.ravel()
r[1] = 10
print r
```

Comment: For some reason, you can't do : `c[0][1] = 10`?

Comment: In your second example c is not a matrix because of your inconsistent dimensions, so there is no meaningful way to do this. Have you considered putting everything in a vector?

Comment: @Divakar that will work. I do have to iterate over each element and wanted to avoid nesting the loop by flattening everything out.

Comment: @massphoenix With that irregular format which forces it to be of object dtype, in most cases you would be iterating anyway.

Comment: @Atnas I haven't but will look in that direction. Do you mean I should have two vectors I could 'ravel' into one array?

Comment: I mean like `c = np.hstack((a,b))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first case `c` is a 2d array

```
In [391]: a = np.asarray([1,2,3])
     ...: b = np.asarray([4,5,6])
     ...: c = np.asarray([a, b])
     ...: 
In [392]: c
Out[392]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
In [393]: c.shape
Out[393]: (2, 3)
```

`ravel` produces a view of `c`, so changes to one appear in the other

```
In [394]: r = c.ravel()
In [395]: r[1] = 10
In [396]: c
Out[396]: 
array([[ 1, 10,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6]])
```

You can also index `c` with `flat`, with the same effect:

```
In [397]: c.flat[4] = 10
In [398]: c
Out[398]: 
array([[ 1, 10,  3],
       [ 4, 10,  6]])
In [399]: r
Out[399]: array([ 1, 10,  3,  4, 10,  6])
```

These changes to `c` or `r` do not affect the original `a` or `b`.  `asarray` copies those arrays.

In the second case `c` is a 1d array containing other arrays:

```
In [400]: a = np.asarray([1,2,3])
     ...: b = np.asarray([4,5,6,7,8])
     ...: c = np.asarray([a, b])
     ...: 
In [401]: c
Out[401]: array([array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8])], dtype=object)
```

The pieces can be joined into a 1d array:

```
In [402]: np.concatenate(c)
Out[402]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Values can be changed, but won't affect the original `c`.

```
In [403]: c[0][0] = 10
In [404]: c
Out[404]: array([array([10,  2,  3]), array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8])], dtype=object)
```

This changes the original `a` because `c` literally contains `a`, not a copy of it:

```
In [405]: a                     
Out[405]: array([10,  2,  3]
```

`np.array` (or `asarray`) tries to make as-a-dimensional array as it can from the inputs.  In the first case inputs are equal in size, so it makes a 2d.  In the second they differ so it makes a 1d array of objects.  This behavior often gives users problems.  Either they expect a 2d array in the second case, or they can't produce the object array in the first.

To reliably make an object array, regardless of whether the inputs match in size or not, you have to do something like

```
In [417]: g = np.empty(2, dtype=object)
In [418]: g[:] = [a, b[:3]]
In [419]: g
Out[419]: array([array([10,  2,  3]), array([4, 5, 6])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It certainly helps me see how I might manipulate it if I were to try to keep pushing this way. Honestly, it seems like a bit too much of a hack around the types so I might just go with iterating over the original structure but this helps me understand things a bit more!