# List of tuples converted to numpy array

Tags: python, list, numpy, tuples

I have a list of tuples, one of them is an object and the other one is generic. When I run `np.asarray(list_in)` the result is a 2D array, with the tuples being converted in a row. However I would like to obtain a 1D array made of tuples.

I could pass a `dtype` to force it and it works well if I try this minimalistic example

```
a = [(1,2),(3,4)]
b = np.asarray(a,dtype=('float,float'))
print b
[( 1.,  2.) ( 3.,  4.)]
```

But how do I take the first element of the list and construct a proper `dtype` out of it. `type(list_in[0])` returns `tuple` and passing this to asarray does not work.

Comment: What is a *proper* dtype ? Why aren't you getting what you're expecting - and what are you *expecting*?

Comment: I assume you want the dtype to be a tuple of types of each element?

Comment: lets say `(MyObject,float)`, but it could also be `(MyObject,anotherObject)`. It is encoded in the first element of the list

Comment: Is `np.array(a, dtype=tuple(type(x) for x in a[0]))` what you're looking for?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes, it is correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With this list of tuples you can make 3 kinds of arrays:

```
In [420]: a = [(1,2),(3,4)]
```

2d array, with dtype inferred from the inputs (but it could also be specified as something like float).  Inputs match in size.

```
In [421]: np.array(a)
Out[421]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Structured array.  1d with 2 fields.  Field indexing by name.  Input must be a list of tuples (not list of lists):

```
In [422]: np.array(a, dtype='i,i')
Out[422]: 
array([(1, 2), (3, 4)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
In [423]: _['f0']
Out[423]: array([1, 3], dtype=int32)
```

In the structured array, input and display uses tuples, but the data is not actually stored as tuples.  The values are packed as bytes - in this case 8 bytes representing 2 integers.

Object array.  This is 1d with tuple contents.  Contents could be anything else.  This is an enhanced/debased list.

```
In [424]: A = np.empty((2,), dtype=object)
In [425]: A[:] = a
In [426]: A
Out[426]: array([(1, 2), (3, 4)], dtype=object)
In [427]: A.shape
Out[427]: (2,)
In [428]: A[1]
Out[428]: (3, 4)
```

`Out[428]` is an actual tuple.  Trying to modify it, `A[1][0]=30`, raises an error.

In this last case `A = np.empty(2, dtype=tuple)` does the same thing.  Any thing other than integer, float, string, etc is 'converted' to `object'.

Simply specifying object dtype doesn't help.  The result is 2d with numeric elements (but stored as object pointers).

```
In [429]: np.array(a, dtype=object)
Out[429]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]], dtype=object)
In [430]: _.shape
Out[430]: (2, 2)
```

More on making an object dtype array at

[numpy ravel on inconsistent dimensional object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565215/numpy-ravel-on-inconsistent-dimensional-object)

Comment: Thank you. This actually works. It is a bit strange that numpy acts so strange

Comment: @RaduIonescu, `numpy` is primarily a multidimensional numeric array tool.  Python already handles lists of diverse objects such as tuples.  `numpy` object arrays don't add much, if any, computing power to the mix.

Comment: The issue is that I am converting to lists back after performing some slicing and wanted to keep the type of the input list

Comment: @RaduIonescu, you may need to ask a new question with more details of how you are processing this list/array.